# Similar to coLinux/Wine to run Linux apps on Windows 64-bit, without bloated and slowly VM?

Tags: windows, linux, emulator, virtualization

I would like to be able to run Linux programs (CLI, maybe GUI) in Windows 10 64-bit, and bonus would be nice to work in the Linux system itself (create files and folders, shell scripts). I used to do this with a virtual machine I installed Linux on, but running a virtual machine takes a long time and it consumes a lot of system resources. I would like to reduce resource consumption and reduce startup time.

What does not work for me:

- [Dual-boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting) (no simultaneous access to Windows and Linux)
- [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol), [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) (I need offline version)
- [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) (requires recompiling source code as far as I know, this takes time)
- [WSL2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (it's slow).

What is close to what I want:

- [coLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_Linux) and forks (nice, but does not support 64-bit Windows)
- [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) (designed to run Windows programs on Linux, I would like the opposite)

Maybe I need something that works with [Compatibility layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_layer) but I didn't find the right program in that list.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you were running WSL2 or WSL1 in your tests? What were you running in your tests? Was is a CPU, IO slowdown, or something else? Normally, they both should have close to native performance, unless the applications you're running need GPU acceleration and don't have access to it. Perhaps WSL1 could be a bit faster due to not having a hardware virtualisaton layer in between, but even then HW virtualisation should be pretty fast.

Comment: Agree with @aitap. Unless you have a very slow or underpowered PC, WSL2 should run anything as fast as it would on native Linux, since it is native Linux. What specifically is your issue?